# Finding the total amount for my query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query that allows me to retrieve customer orders.

```
Select ID, OrderID, Item, Price from customerOrders
Where Order = 1
```

is there a way of totalling up the final amount to pay and have it visible below, but still be able to view all details needed in the sql query, for example

```
ID    |  OrderID |  Item  | Price
1     |   1      |  Book  | 9.99
2     |   1      |  DVD   | 12.99

                    total = 22.98
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps:

1, To generate the SUM, you need to add it to the result set using UNION ALL.  UNION adds a DISTINCT operation which isn't required, even if in your case it won't change the result.

```
Select ID, OrderID, Item, Price from customerOrders
Where [Order] = 1
UNION ALL
Select NULL, NULL, NULL, SUM(Price) from customerOrders
Where [Order] = 1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ID IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, ID;
```

2, To sort it in the order you want (sum at the bottom), you can use the NULL ID as an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [COMPUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181708%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
Select ID, OrderID, Item, Price from customerOrders
Where Order = 1
COMPUTE SUM(Price)
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the thing you want is called a roll-up row. SQL Server has a special function for such cases, it's called `ROLLUP()` and used inside a `GROUP BY` clause. In your particular situation, the query would basically look like this:

```
SELECT ID, OrderID, Item, SUM(Price) AS Price
FROM customerOrders
WHERE OrderID = 1
GROUP BY ROLLUP((ID, OrderID, Item))
;
```

You can see a live demonstration of this query [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1c01/1). More information about `ROLLUP()`, as well as other GROUP BY functions, can be found [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
   Select ID, OrderID, Item, Price from customerOrders
   Where Order = 1
Union
   Select NULL, NULL, NULL, (
      Select Sum(Price) from customerOrders
      Where Order = 1
      Group By  Order
   )
```

**UPDATE**

Incase the result was empty, the total should be zero, not empty. Use the updated code.

Cheers

Comment: i'm trying to use 'union all' instead of just 'union' to prevent unexpectected application of 'dictinct' command to result

Comment: in case if in the first query will be any records equal to record from the 2nd query that record from 2nd query will be omitted.

Comment: If you use UNION ALL it won't happen. Also I think you should take it easy. When the invoice is empty, there is no total amount for that. yeah?

Comment: Yep, that's what i tried to say. In your answer I didn't see any `all` and said it just in case.